# Vb.net - call child method from parent class (vb.net Polymorphism)

Tags: vb.net, polymorphism

I'm a newbie with Vb.net and I try to perform polymorphism.

It's my interface "IMyConnection"

```
Imports System.Data.Common

Interface IMyConnection
    Sub openConnection()
    Sub closeConnection()
    Function getConnection() As DbConnection
    Function executeQuery(ByVal querySelect As String) As DbCommand
    Function executeUpdate(ByVal queryUpdate As String) As Boolean
End Interface
```

In Main class, I create a new instance like this

```
Dim connection As IMyConnection
connection = New AccessConnection()
```

but when I call a function that never declare in IMyConnection

```
connection.setDataSource("D:\Access DB\mdb\Akademik.mdb")
```

I get error message

```
'setDataSource' is not a member of 'WindowsApplication1.IMyConnection'
```

so to handle that error, I create new object like this

```
Dim accessConnection As AccessConnection = connection
accessConnection.setDataSource("D:\Access DB\mdb\Akademik.mdb")
```

Please help me solve this problem, I can't find any keyword to find the better solutions
Thanks

Comment: The interface, IMyConnection, has no knowledge of the setDataSource method. That's why it doesn't work. You can solve this by casting the interface to the AccessConnection type with Ctype/Directcast for example.

Comment: Thanks, I found some example about casting type in vb, and this code also work..

Dim accessConnection As AccessConnection = CType(connection, AccessConnection)
accessConnection.setDataSource("D:\Access DB\mdb\Akademik.mdb")